# Would sharing patient data improve health Care?

Tags: medications, research

I believe information about a patient is key in medical practitioners. In most cases people seek medication where they find convenient to them. If one has to access medication in another health facility other that his/her own in different city, country or continent. Would sharing of patient data, like what have been done in most countries, improve medication, time, resources and saving Life?

Comment: Such data are already shared through the studies, books, medical conferences, doctors who developed successful treatment techniques teaching students on various universities or doctors in other hospitals, etc.

Comment: I took situation where i got medical file in one facility, If i seek medication in other city, town or continent how can this facility get my medical history so that i get better treatment. Not about scholarly articles

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if a doctor in France could type something into a computer and see all my records from Canada, that doctor would give me better care than if the only source of information was my memory. Heck, if a doctor in another province in Canada could do that, I would also get better care. All my previous diagnoses and prescriptions would be there, prior surgeries, and so on. I wouldn't have to spend time filling out forms and listing these sorts of things.

But that's not really the question. Such a system would have costs as well as benefits. Software development is difficult and expensive, and if you get it wrong, care could be actively worsened. (Say a patient tells the doctor something that isn't on the system and the doctor assumes the patient is misremembering, and the consequences cause harm to the patient.) A study on that was [published](https://www.upi.com/Health_News/2018/03/28/Electronic-medical-records-carry-some-risks-study-says/8981522261254/) this year. In some countries, the information could be mis-used to discriminate against a patient or harass them. Imagine a doctor in Country A reporting someone to the police because of information recorded in Country B about their sexuality or recreational drug use. Or an insurance company in Country A refusing to cover a procedure because of information recorded in Country B. The Daily Mail isn't exactly a reliable source, never mind a scientific journal, but here's an [article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2851254/NHS-carry-selling-patients-medical-data-insurance-firms-despite-history-blunders-illegal-use-information.html) about the NHS selling medical data. Whether it is currently happening or not, it certainly could happen with any new system that was developed. And there's even an issue that [doctors might reject difficult patients](https://www.verywellhealth.com/doctors-reject-difficult-patients-deny-medical-care-2615006) if notes in the record suggested they were a "PITA".

What's more, paper always works. There are not competing standards for it. Photocopying (or printing another copy) is simple enough, and faxes still exist, or things can be scanned and emailed. Some medical facilities might not be able to afford the systems to read records electronically, but could use and maintain paper records just fine.

All of the legal, privacy, and translation issues would have to be worked out and agreed to by a large number of countries. And someone would have to fund it and test it. It would not be a trivial undertaking. So the question isn't "would there be an improvement in care for some patients" but "would the 
improvement in care for some patients outweigh the worse care for other patients, the privacy and legal issues, and the financial cost of developing the system and connecting everyone to it?"

Comment: True. If litigation are worked out well I believe something can be done. There are other systems like security that share information with strict policies and terms that has worked and though healthcare is different, i believe this will work.